# Error deploying plugin to jira

Tags: java, classloader, classnotfoundexception, classcastexception, jira-plugin

I'm trying to deploy my custom plugin to jira and then the error occurs:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory
```

The project is build with Maven and if I remove and exclude every

```
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
```

dependency
// I just paniced :)
logs inform about ClassNotFoundException
I have no idea what to do, so can anybody help?

Comment: Please post whole pom.xml and whole stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have no idea why this bug occured, but I rolled back and reconfigured all my pom files, and I believe that the issue was in incorrect api dependency. It concerns QuickBooks API v3, and now it works fine with

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.code.devkit.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>ipp-v3-java-devkit</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And, probably, the problem was in one one these dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit</groupId>
        <artifactId>ipp-java-devkit</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.code.devkit</groupId>
        <artifactId>ipp-java-qbhelper</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```